# regular expression in python with %

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regular expressions in general, but I could not find a special rule about the `%` char.

I do the following:

```
line = parseFileHandle.readline()
while 1:
    line = parseFileHandle.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    # test for string '%%?'
    match = re.match("%%?", line)
    if match:
        print (line)
```

that however prints out any line that starts with a `%` char. That is not what I want.

In the end I want to find out the file name (myfile.tex) that is in the file in this form

```
%%?  file: myfile.tex
```

Comment: '%' is not a regular expression

Comment: '%%' is just the escape notation for *one* '%s' character. If you want to search for '%%' then you need '%%%%'.

Comment: @CRUSADER: % is just a plain character, unless you are performing "%" substitution o n a string. Your comment above escaping "%" does not apply in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the `%`. It's the `?` that has special meaning: it makes the second `%` optional. Thus your regex would match `%` and `%%`.

The following regex should work:

```
match = re.match("%%[?]", line)
```

If you are searching for `%%?` at the start of the line, then regular expressions are not necessary. The following will achieve the same thing:

```
if line.startswith("%%?"):
```

Answer (score 4):

`.startswith()` is probably the best function in this case. You don't need regex here.

Also, it looks like you're reading a file in a slightly strange way. The usual syntax is:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('%%?'):
            print(line)
```

Comment: This is however hard to find in any tutorial including the python tutorial... But good to know

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: Most of the common Python tutorials are a little outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the file names from your list can be done like this with a regular expression:

```
exp = re.compile("^%%\?  file: ([^ \n]+)$")
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        match = exp.match(line)
        if match:
            print(match.group(1))
```

As others have pointed out, you needed to escape the `?` character in your original attempt - as it has special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: Won't that group grab the linebreak (e.g. `\n`) too?

Answer (score 0):

```
if line.startswith('%%?'):
   # do something
```

is likely what you want

Answer (score 0):

`?` in regex is quantifier and means:

> ***`?`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or one time.

for matching `?` character you have to use `\?` (character escape) or `[?]` (character group)